# How to use groupBy when you have 2 different groupings?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have this sample data

```
1/14/2012,5,Gas
1/15/2012,5,Gas
1/16/2012,5,Gas
1/17/2012,5,Gas
1/18/2012,5,Gas
1/19/2012,5,Gas
1/20/2012,5,Gas
1/21/2012,5,Gas
1/22/2012,5,Gas
1/23/2012,5,Gas
1/24/2012,5,Gas
1/25/2012,5,Gas
1/26/2012,5,Gas
1/27/2012,5,Gas
1/28/2012,5,Gas
1/29/2012,5,Gas
1/30/2012,5,Gas
1/31/2012,5,Gas
02/01/2012,5,Gas
```

Sometimes I want to group by "Month" and "Year" sometimes I just want to group by "Year"

```
  IEnumerable<IGrouping<TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear, TransactionDto>> groupTransactions = null;

DollarCapPeriod dollarCapPeriod = (DollarCapPeriod)Enum.Parse(typeof(DollarCapPeriod), reward.DollarCapPeriod);
switch (dollarCapPeriod)
{
    case DollarCapPeriod.Monthly:
  groupTransactions = filterdTransactions.GroupBy(x => new TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear { Month = x.TransactionDate.Month, Year = x.TransactionDate.Year });
        break;
    case DollarCapPeriod.Yearly:
  groupTransactions = filterdTransactions.GroupBy(x => new TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear { Month = 0, Year = x.TransactionDate.Year });
        break;
    default:
        break;
}


public class TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear
    {
        public int Month { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }

    }
```

The above code is what I have so far. The Month one works. It is the year one that fails. I am trying to use concrete glass for the grouping but it not working. I was told to set Month to zero to basically have it ignore Month and group it as if it was only using year but that does not work.

When it groups them it just groups them into 19 groups(basically one for each record). When I look at the debugger I see the data like this

```
   foreach (var group in groupTransactions)
            {
                var key = group.Key;
                int Month = key.Month;
                int Year = key.Year;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Month: {0}, Year: {1}", Month, Year);
            }
```

results

```
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
Month: 0, Year: 2012
```

When it should just be 1 record with all of them grouped. As they are all from 2012

**Edit**

Scott Rippey - I tried what you given but I still don't have it working.

```
 groupTransactions = filterdTransactions.GroupBy(
                            // Key selector:
                            x => x.TransactionDate.Year,
                            // result selector:
                            (year, items) => new TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear{ Year = year, Month = 0, Transactions = items});


public class TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear
{
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public IList<TransactionDto> Transactions { get; set; }

}

Error   1   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>' because it is not a delegate type
```

**Edit 2**

I just noticed you have item.toList()

Now I get this

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CCRecomendator.Framework.Domain.DTO.TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear>' 
                                        to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<CCRecomendator.Framework.Domain.DTO.TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear,CCRecomendator.Framework.Domain.DTO.TransactionDto>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

So the problem that I am seeing is that this returns a different type. I need to have the "Month" and "Yearly" switch grouping code to return the same datatype(otherwise I would just use the an anonymous type).

Comment: Please include some info about `TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear`.  What is it, and how is it used?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right code?  I'm expecting to see a `Transactions` property in addition to `Month` and `Year`.

Comment: Probably not. Like I said this is what another person told me to do. So I tried it and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why GroupBy isn't working

`TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear` doesn't override the **equality operator**, so `GroupBy` will use **reference comparison** -- in other words, no two `TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear` will be equal when comparing.

The easiest solution is to do what you did in the first example ... use an anonymous object instead.  Anonymous objects automatically override the equality operators, and they're perfect for `GroupBy` operations.

Otherwise, you'll have to override `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` methods in your `TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear` class.

### Why are you using GroupBy?

Do you actually need **lists** of grouped items for each year?  If you just want to get a distinct list of years, you shouldn't be using `GroupBy`, you should be using `Distinct`.

Judging by the name of `TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear`, I see `Month` and `Year` but I'm guessing you're supposed to also have a `Transactions` property.  If that's true, then keep reading.

It looks like your code is trying to output **lists of grouped items** stored in `TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear`.
To do this, you should use the following overload: [`GroupBy(keySelector, resultSelector)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx).

Basically, this overload allows you to do something with each matching group -- such as create a `TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear`:

```
groupTransactions = filterdTransactions.GroupBy(
    // Key selector:
    x => new { x.Year },
    // result selector:
    (key, items) => new TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear{ Year = key.Year, Month = 0, Transactions = items.ToList()})
);
```

### Re: Edit 2

The reason you're seeing the error in your **Edit 2** is because the following line:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear, TransactionDto>> groupTransactions = null;
```

should be:

```
IEnumerable<TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear> groupTransactions = null;
```

You simply declared it the wrong type.

Comment: So I need to add a collection of TransactionDtos what is Items?

Comment: Ok I tried to it but I keep getting an error(see my edit). I would love to use anonymous types but as you can see I have a switch statement and in some cases I want to group by Month and Year sometimes just by Year but I want to later on return transactionsDto but I can't do that with an anonymous type.

Comment: Yes, you need to add a collection of `TransactionDto`s to your `TransactionsGroupedByMonthYear` object.